# Conceptual question:Is it possible to find three linearly dependent vectors in $R^3$ such that none of the three is a multiple of another?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find three linearly dependent vectors in $R^3$ such that none of the three is a multiple of another?

I don't think so because by definition of linear dependence, we can always find a vector that is a scalar multiple of another. Still, I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any three vectors in a plane are linearly dependent.  If no two are parallel they are not scalar multiples.  So we can take $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)$ as our three vectors and note that $(1,0,0)+(0,1,0)+(-1)\cdot(1,1,0)=(0,0,0)$ to show they are linearly dependent.

Comment: so none of the three is a multiple of another doesn't mean a linear combination of the other two? I think it makes sense now.

Comment: Another way to express linear dependence is that one vector is a linear combination of the rest.  That is different from being a scalar multiple of one of the rest, as this example shows.